# Validation on text on alphabets enter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

Any one use AngulerJS Validation on TextBox. So that only enter alphabets.

Answer (score 20):

Depending on what you want:

Alphabets and blankspace:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"
```

Alphabets no blankspace:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess all the other answers using ng-pattern are correct but just to mention, the use of `ng-model` is compulsory with `ng-pattern`.

The complete input can be:

```
 <input type="text" ng-pattern ="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/" ng-model="Name" />
```

This will accept the alphabets and the spaces only.

Comment: I want accents in the vowels (i.e. áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ). How can I do it? @Prateek

Comment: [UPDATE] this regex working for me: `/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s]*$/`

Answer (score 0):

There is a directive called `ng-pattern` it allows to use regular expressions to indicate which are the allowed values.

It can be used like this:

```
<input ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z]/" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your input

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ng-pattern for whateever reason, you can also add validating functions to the ng-modal-controller that is set up on your textbox, specifically to the formatters and parsers arrays. A good description of how to do this is here: http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html. Another alternative is to use a published directive to achieve the same purpose, I haven't used this one myself but it seems legit: http://www.brentmckendrick.com/code/xtform/